# How do i set proxy for ie in python webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, webdriver

I'm using this code:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.server.address")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", "port_number")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

to set proxy for FireFox in python webdriver. This works for FireFox. How to set proxy like this in ie?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I did it like this:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
caps["proxy"] = { "proxyType": "manual", "httpProxy": "localhost:8086" }
driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities = caps)
```

If you are using browsermob proxy (like I am), it'd look like this:

```
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
caps["proxy"] = { "proxyType": "manual", "httpProxy": proxy.proxy }
driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities = caps)
```

Answer (score -2):

use:

```
webdriver.Ie
```

See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html, you will have to install the webdriver for internet Explorer for selenium to use it

Comment: yes,I know how to use this code to start IE, but I don't know how to set up proxy for IE.

Comment: What Joe said. This starts IE, but doesn't indicate how to set the proxy for IE (which, incidentally, is just the system proxy... unless you're using selenium server, then it's another ball game) which is what the original question asked.